# convert two dimensional array to object array without duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a two dimensional array of colors:

```
var colors = [["Blue", "Red"],["Green","Red"],["Black","Orange"],["Red", "Blue"]]
```

I want to turn this into an object array and I've successfully done so using a .map

```
obj = colors.map(function(x) {return
{    
    "color1": x[0],
    "color2": x[1]  
}});
```

However I want the new object array to exclude duplicates and just be a list of the colors mentioned (instead of color1 and color2, combine into one). New array should have the format:

```
[{"color": Blue},
 {"color": Red},
 {"color": Green},
 {"color": Black},
 {"color": Orange}]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Any chance you know which version of Javascript you're using?

Answer (score 0):

In plain javascript.

```
var colors = [["Blue", "Red"],["Green","Red"],["Black","Orange"],["Red", "Blue"]]

var map = {};
var result = [];
colors.forEach(
    function (pair) {
      pair.forEach(
          function (color) {
            if (!map.hasOwnProperty(color)) {
              result.push(color);
            }
            map[color] = 1;
          })
    }
);

console.log(result);
```

This is much easier to do in later versions of javascript. You could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) type to de-dupe for instance.

Even easier with a nice utility library. In [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/) for instance:

```
_(colors).flatten().uniq().value();
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use Array [**filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) & [**map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) methods to achieve this.

**DEMO**

```js
// Initial multidimensional array.
var colors = [
               ["Blue", "Red"],
               ["Green","Red"],
               ["Black","Orange"],
               ["Red", "Blue"]
             ];

// Merged colors into single dimensional array.
var merged = [].concat.apply([], colors);

// Apply array filter() method to remove the duplicates.
var filteredData = merged.filter(function(item, index) { 
  return merged.indexOf(item) == index 
});

// Create an array of objects from the array "filteredData".
var res = filteredData.map(function(item) {
  return {    
    "color": item
  }
});

// result
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use js [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to remove duplicate instance from Array.

```js
var colors = [["Blue", "Red"],["Green","Red"],["Black","Orange"],["Red", "Blue"]];
//Merge array
var merged = [].concat.apply([], colors);
//Remove duplicates
var removeDuplicates = Array.from( new Set(merged));  
//create the array of object
var o = removeDuplicates.map(function(obj) { 
  return {"color":obj};
});

console.log(o);
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saidulu401/nL6yugj9/1/)